# Rails 3 Implementation With a Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm programming a web based game and as you can imagine, it is pretty vital that i write some good code in order to be able to preserve the game and not have too many problems in the future.

As you can guess, a game has some values and functions that do not really fit to a model (or at least fitting it would make the model too fat i think). For instance, think of a case where you want to calculate the experience formula for a given monster or when you want to calculate the health of a monster, user etc based on their hp points.

I guess that all these could still fit to a user or monster model, but in my opinion, it would make it a hell to make changes in all shorts of places around different models. Moreover, a monster has hp, a user has hp, it would be weird to have the same functions in 2 or more different models (thus, not DRY).

So, i'm thinking of using a module like "game_engine/formulas" and extend it with more things if something comes up.

But i wanted some expert opinion about it. Would you do it this way ? Or is there something better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to share code that applies to multiple models, a module is a good way to do so. Then you can simply put `Include MyModule` in each model. But a module should be somewhat abstract, and shouldn't have any knowledge of which model its code is currently operating in, i.e. it shouldn't try and "detect" what model its in, but it is perfectly okay for it to get information from the containing model by calling the model's methods or accessing its attributes.

Comment: yes, i was thinking of passing, say health points, as an argument to calculate how much hp certain health points give, and so on. I also think that this is probably the way to go for it. Thanx :)

Comment: You don't even have to pass anything, since when you include a module in a model, all the methods in the module essentially become a part of the model. So you can just directly access the model's methods and attributes from within the module. Though this means that every model the module is included in needs to have those methods/attributes the module is using.

Comment: hmm, this can be a bit tricky i guess. Maybe hp, for instance can be done as a virtual attribute, indeed. Needs some thinking on if i would want to do it this way or not.

Comment: It's a good idea to write/draw your design on paper. Write out all your models and draw how they're interconnected, and write out the attributes and methods each has and see if there's any methods that are duplicated and could be put into a module as shared functionality.